# Python: match correct datetime.datetime format

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

In my Python script, I pass a commandline option `--before` with a `date` argument, i.e.

```
myscript.py --before 2014-Aug-02
```

I then need to read it into my variable. I want to support several possible date formats, i.e.  `2014-Aug-02`, `2014-08-02`, `2014-08`, ...

In my script, I have following construct to try to match the provided date format, but it looks to me very ugly. Is there a better, more elegant way to do it?

```
if args.before:
    try:
        BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], "%Y-%b-%d")
    except ValueError:
        try:
            BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], "%Y-%b")
        except ValueError:
            try:
                 BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], "%Y-%m")
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], "%Y")
                    except ValueError:
                        print 'time data %s does not match format' % args.before[0]
                        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally use the [`dateutil` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) to parse arbitrary dates:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
try:
    BEFORE = date_parse(args.before[0])
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print 'time data %s does not match format' % args.before[0]
    exit(1)
```

The `dateutil` parser can handle all formats you want to support plus more.

But if you don't want to install an external dependency, then create a *list* of supported formats, and use a loop:

```
formats = ('%Y-%b-%d', '%Y-%b', '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y-%m', '%Y')
for format in formats:
    try:
        BEFORE = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], format)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
else:
    print 'time data %s does not match format' % args.before[0]
    exit(1)
```

As soon as a working format is found, the loop is ended with a `break`, otherwise the `else:` suite of the `for` loop is reached, and an error message is printed. Note that an `else:` suite of a loop is *not* executed when you break out early.

Answer (score 2):

```
acceptedFormats = ("%Y-%b-%d", "%Y-%b", "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m", "%Y")
if args.before:
    for format in acceptedFormats:
        try:
            before = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.before[0], format)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        print 'time data %s does not match format' % args.before[0]
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
def validate_date(datestr):
    for format in ("%Y-%b-%d", "%Y-%b", ...):
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, format)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        print 'time data %s does not match format' % datestr
        exit(1)
```

Then:

```
BEFORE = validate_date(args.before[0])
```

The `else` block on a `for` loop runs if the loop reaches an end without `break` or `return`, which in this case only happens if no `format` ever successfully parses the `datestr`.

---

If, like @poke, you prefer to have the function not `exit` the whole script (as may not always be appropriate), you can remove `exit(1)` from the function entirely (which will therefore implicitly `return None` if no `format` matches) and do something like:

```
BEFORE = validate_date(args.before[0])
if BEFORE is None:
    exit(1)
```

You could alternatively move the whole `else` block outside the function, as you might not always want it to `print` anything, either.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I’d personally not want to have a function (used for validation) be able to exit the script.